# Proper DB schema to store video statistics

Tags: php, mysql

I have 100 videos in my website. if I have to store IP address from which the clicks are made, country and time clicked, Do I need to create a seperate table for each video (100 tables in my case).
My sample table schema for video ID:1

```
Table name: ID_1
IP_address | country | time
```

What are the alternative ways I can do this. (I don't want to use Google Analytics as I want to try this for my self first)

I am using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to create a seperate table for each video (100 tables in my case)

Please plase **don't**!

Just add a column to your table that works as a foreign key to your videos table. Also, add a column for primary key and a few more:

```
Table name: videos_clicks
id | video_id | ip_address | clicks | country | last_time
Primary key: id
Unique Index: video_id, IP_address
```

You can then work with this very simply. For example, to insert a new row:

```
INSERT INTO videos_clicks (video_id, ip_address, clicks, country, last_time)
VALUES (1, '123.45.67.89', 1, 'country_name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clicks = clicks + 1, last_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Or to get all click for a video with ID '1':

```
SELECT id, ip_address, clicks, country, last_time
FROM videos_clicks
WHERE video_id = '1'
```

---

You also might want to consider creating a table `countries` and replacing the `country` varchar/text column to numeric `country_id` that would point to the `countries` table:

```
Table name: countries
id  |  name  |  twoletter | threeletter
-----------------------------------
 1  Andorra      AD         AND
 2  Afghanistan  AF         AFG
...
-----------------------------------
Primary key: id
```

Please read something about [databaze normalizing](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm). It's going to make your application much more effective and in the end make your life simpler.

Comment: @Cezechnology: Thanks alot for the answer. I have one more question: How can I ensure that those clicks are unique, meaning I should not insert if one person clicks the same link twice.

Comment: @Mahin, that's what the UNIQUE index is for! If you set it on the two columns video_id and ip_address, it will allow only for one ip per video. And in the INSERT statement, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` just updates the time of last visit and raises the number of visits by one.